# SELECT com PDO e PHP OO

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Eu estou começando a pouco tempo meu estudo sobre PHPOO, saindo mais da área de Estruturado... E após alguns estudos, obtive uma parte do conhecimento, porém ao tentar fazer uma buscar no banco de dados para verificar a existência do seguinte usuário, me retornou o seguinte erro.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in D:\Programas\xamp\htdocs\eventos.php:39 Stack trace: #0 D:\Programas\xamp\htdocs\eventos.php(48): Usuarios->getUsuario('daniel@servidor...', '123') #1 {main} thrown in D:\Programas\xamp\htdocs\eventos.php on line 39

```
<?php
class Conexao{
    private static $host = "localhost";
    private static $db = "esa";
    private static $user = "root";
    private static $pass = "";

    public function __construct(){}

    public function __clone(){}

    public function getHost(){return self::$host;}
    public function getDB(){return self::$db;}
    public function getUser(){return self::$user;}
    public function getPass(){return self::$pass;}

    public function connect(){
        try {
            $this->conexao = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->getHost().";dbname=".$this->getDB()."", $this->getUser(), $this->getPass());
        }
        catch (PDOException $i)
        {
            die("Erro: <code>" . $i->getMessage() . "</code>");
        }
    }
}

class Usuarios{
    private $email;
    private $senha;

    public function __construct(){}

    public function getUsuario($email, $senha){
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->senha = md5($senha);
        $cn = new Conexao();
        $con = $cn->connect();
        $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_usuarios WHERE email = :email AND senha = :senha");
        $sql->bindValue(":email", $this->email);
        $sql->bindValue(":senha", $this->senha);
        $sql->execute();
        echo $sql->rowCount();
    }
}

$user = new Usuarios();
echo $user->getUsuario("daniel@servidor.com", "123");
?>
```

Comment: Acredito que a conexão inválida pois os atributos da classe estão como `static` e no método de conexão você usa `$this->getHost()`. Acredito que o melhor seja deixar tudo estático. Aquele `$cn = new Conexao();` fica bem estranho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua função de conexão não retorna nada.

```
$con = $cn->connect();
```

Então é atribuido `null` a `$con`

```
public function connect(){
    try {
        $this->conexao = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->getHost().";dbname=".$this->getDB()."", $this->getUser(), $this->getPass());
        // aqui você deve retornar sua conexão
        return $this->conexao;
    }
    catch (PDOException $i)
    {
        die("Erro: <code>" . $i->getMessage() . "</code>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara, você é um DEUS KKKKKK, Muito obrigado mano. Mais uma que eu aprendi. Valeu mesmo.